# How to integrate exponent of sine?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I am trying to integrate Abs|E^ $\sin \theta$| (the absolute value of Euler's constant to the power of sin(theta), and tried the code `Integrate[Abs[E^Sin[x]], x]` but it returned as `\[Integral]E^Re[Sin[x]] \[DifferentialD]x`

Could someone please show me how to correctly integrate the function?
Thanks, and sorry in advance for the corrections you would have to make to this post!

Comment: I am sure the antiderivative under consideration has no closed-form expression. Think of the function NIntegrate[Abs[E^Sin[t]], {t, 0, x}].

Comment: Or better, to make @user64494's point more clear: ``Plot[NIntegrate[RealAbs[E^Sin[x]], {x, -10, t}],{t, -10, 10}]``

Comment: thanks for your clarification, @b3m2a1

Comment: thank you for your advice, @user64494 !

Answer (score 3):

Check this numerical treatment:

```
g[t_] := Abs[E^Sin[t]]
nsol = Table[NIntegrate[g[t], {t, 0, x}], {x, -10, 10, .1}]; 
f[x_] = Interpolation[Thread@{Table[x, {x, -10, 10, .1}], nsol}, x]
Plot[f[x], {x, -1, 1}]
```

Now this `f[x]` can be used in further calculations!

[image]

Let's check the obtained interpolated function `f(x)` is correct or not!

```
 NIntegrate[g[t], {t, -10, 10}]  = 25.0755
 f[10] - f[-10]                  = 25.0755
```

Hope This helps!

Comment: it does, @Sachin Kumar ! Thanks so much for ur help

Comment: @wendy, Good that it has helped you, Pl accept the answer.

Comment: Better to use `FunctionInterpolation`. It'll be smarter about how it chooses points and the tests I've run suggest it's about four times as accurate as this method. Also it's faster. If you want to stick with `Interpolation`, at the very least it makes sense to create the grid of points and the interpolated values in the same `Table` call.